# Как обнулить List вывод которого реализуется в JTextArea JAVA

Tags: java, list, объекты, textarea

столкнулся с проблемой! List нужно выводить после нажатия кнопки в TextArea. Лист формируется в зависимости от выбранных RadioButton.
Повторно нажимая кнопку, сообщение не удаляется, а просто увеличивается. более подробное описание ниже:

Есть программа по поиску в которой присутствуют JRadioButtons, JTextArea и кнопка JButton после нажатия которой в JTextArea, выводится List который фильтрует другой лист с неким объемом элементов (замена БД).  в зависимости от выбранных JRadioButtons (параметров для поиcка list) фильтры меняются.

Проблема в том, что после нажатия JButton, результат в  JTextArea удовлетворяет первый раз, а потом например если ещё раз нажать, то результат просто добавляется к прошлому и при повторном нажатии ещё раз добавляется. А Если поменять параметры поиска, то просто то, что накопилось, заменяется на другие элементы + добавится ещё 1, а количество добавленного сохраняется. (видно на скринах ниже).

Поиск реализован созданием нового List который фильтрует по определённым характеристикам другой List. Я понимаю так, что каждый раз создается новый List (выделяется память для него) и по этому он растёт.
Но как остановить это, что бы он каждый раз после нажатия обнулялся ?

Т.е. Как сделать так, чтобы в JTextArea после нажатия JButton "Начать поиск арматуры" не добавлялся результат поиска к прошлому результату, а был как после 1го нажатия JButton, а не увеличивался итд.

Вот скрины программы + код:

Вот программа

[image: Вот программа]

После 1 нажатия JButton "Начать поиск арматуры"

[image: Вот после 1 нажатия JButton]

После 3 нажатий JButton с такими же параметрами

[image: После 3 нажатий JButton с такими же параметрами]

Вот нажатие с другими параметрами и как видим, просто заменились старые выводы на новые

[image: Вот нажатие с другими параметрами и как видим, просто заменились старые выводы на новые]

а вот Код основных моментов реализации поиска, надеюсь всё понятно:

Вот List в котором весь объем данных (для удобства уменьшу объем данных)

```
   public class ArmatureList {
   public static List<CreateArmature> valvesList = new ArrayList<>();

   public static void setValvesListList() {  
    valvesList.add(new CreateArmature
            ("Клапан", "Бабочка", "Фланцевое", "Бронза",
                    "Проходной", 40, 16, 4620, 0,
                    " иммется возможность установки ручного дублера")) ;
    valvesList.add(new CreateArmature
            ("Клапан", "Бабочка", "Фланцевое", "Бронза",
                    "Проходной", 50, 16, 4620, 0,
                    " иммется возможность установки ручного дублера"));
    valvesList.add(new CreateArmature
            ("Клапан", "Бабочка", "Фланцевое", "Чугун с шар. граф.",
                    "Проходной", 40, 16, 4620, 0,
                    " иммется возможность установки ручного дублера")) ;
    valvesList.add(new CreateArmature
            ("Клапан", "Бабочка", "Фланцевое", "Чугун с шар. граф.",
                    "Проходной", 600, 10, 4620, 0,
                    " иммется возможность установки ручного дублера " +
                            "диаметры 600+ изготавливаются на заказ "));
}
}
```

Вот класс Create Armatura по которому создается лист с данными (в нём вроде бы не чего необычного)

```
public class CreateArmature {

private final String name;//имя
private final String typeOfUse;// тип использования
private final String connectionType;// тип соединения
private final String bodyComposition;// матриал корпуса
private final String typeOfConstruction;// Конструкция (проход/угл)
private final int DN;// DN
private final int PN;// PN
private final int fig;// fig.
private final int price;// цена
private final String comments;//Комментарии

public CreateArmature
        (String name, String typeOfUse, String connectionType,
         String bodyComposition, String typeOfConstruction,
         int DN, int PN, int fig, int price, String comments) {
    this.name = name; // 1
    this.typeOfUse = typeOfUse;// 2
    this.connectionType = connectionType;// 3
    this.bodyComposition = bodyComposition;// 4
    this.typeOfConstruction = typeOfConstruction;// 5
    this.DN = DN;// 6
    this.PN = PN;// 7
    this.fig = fig;// 8
    this.price = price;
    this.comments = comments;

}


public String getName() {  //1
    return name;
}
public String getTypeOfUse() {  //2
    return typeOfUse;
}

public String getConnectionType() {  //3
    return connectionType;
}

public String getBodyComposition() {  //4
    return bodyComposition;
}

public String getTypeOfConstruction() {//5
    return typeOfConstruction;
}

public int getDN() {  //6
    return DN;
}

public int getPN() {  //7
    return PN;
}

public int getFig() {  //8
    return fig;
}
public int getPrice() {  //9
    return price;
}
public String getComments() {  //10
    return comments;
}



@Override
public String toString() {
    return  name + " " + typeOfUse  + " " + connectionType + " соединение"  + " "+ bodyComposition  + " "+ typeOfConstruction + " DN " + DN + " PN " + PN + " фиг."+ fig +
            (price == 0 ? "" : (" примерная цена " + price)) + "\nКомментарий: " + comments + "\n\n";

}}}
```

А вот класс который описывает нажатие кнопки!!! Алгоритм такой, что идёт проверка всех JRadioButton и полей для заполнений и если все параметры выбраны, то мы попадаем в условие выполнения поиска по Листу valvesList, а если нет, то выводится сообщение о невыбранных параметрах

```
           class ButtonEveLists implements ActionListener {
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ArmatureList.setValvesListList();


        if ((проходнаяRadioButton.isSelected() ||
                угроловаяRadioButton.isSelected())

                &&

                (запорнаяRadioButton1.isSelected() ||
                        запорнаясСильфоннымУплотнениемRadioButton.isSelected() ||
                        невозратнаяОбратнаяRadioButton.isSelected() ||
                        невозвратноЗапорнаяRadioButton1.isSelected() ||
                        невозвратноПриемнаяRadioButton.isSelected() ||
                        бабочкаRadioButton.isSelected() ||
                        задвижкиRadioButton.isSelected() ||
                        ножевыеЗадвижкиRadioButton.isSelected())

                &&

                (бронзаRadioButton.isSelected() ||
                        бронзаRadioButton.isSelected() ||
                        стальRadioButton.isSelected() ||
                        нержСтальRadioButton.isSelected() ||
                        чугунRadioButton.isSelected() ||
                        чугунСШарГрафRadioButton.isSelected() ||
                        латуньRadioButton.isSelected())

                &&

                (фланцеваяRadioButton.isSelected() ||
                        межфланцеваяRadioButton.isSelected() ||
                        муфтоваяRadioButton.isSelected() ||
                        штуцернаяRadioButton.isSelected() ||
                        цапковаяRadioButton.isSelected() ||
                        подПриваркуRadioButton.isSelected())

                &&

                (PNTextField.getText().length() != 0)

                &&

                (textField1DN.getText().length() != 0)

        ) {



            selectedCharacteristics();

            int dn = Integer.parseInt(textField1DN.getText());
            int pn = Integer.parseInt(PNTextField.getText());

            List<CreateArmature> searchResult = new ArmatureSearch()
                    .setBodyComposition(bodyComposition)
                    .setTypeOfUse(typeOfUse)
                    .setConnectionType(connectionType)
                    .setTypeOfConstruction(typeOfConstruction)
                    .setDN(dn)
                    .setMinPn(pn)
                    .search(ArmatureList.valvesList);
            textAreaResultsSearchArm.setText(String.valueOf(searchResult));
            clearListArm();

        } else {
            textAreaResultsSearchArm.setText("Проверьте выбранные хиарактеристики, возможно " +
                    "вы допустили ошибку или не чего не найдено \n");
        }
    }
}
```

Вот метод   selectedCharacteristics() который мы видим в Условии, когда после проверок всех JRadioButton попадаем в условие для поиска по листу valvesList.

```
    public void selectedCharacteristics() {


    if (бронзаRadioButton.isSelected()) {
        bodyComposition = "Бронза";
    } else if (стальRadioButton.isSelected()) {
        bodyComposition = "Сталь";
    } else if (нержСтальRadioButton.isSelected()) {
        bodyComposition = "Нерж. сталь";
    } else if (чугунRadioButton.isSelected()) {
        bodyComposition = "чугун";
    } else if (чугунСШарГрафRadioButton.isSelected()) {
        bodyComposition = "Чугун с шар. граф.";
    } else if (латуньRadioButton.isSelected()) {
        bodyComposition = "Латунь";
    }

    if (запорнаяRadioButton1.isSelected()) {
        typeOfUse = "Запорный";
    } else if (запорнаясСильфоннымУплотнениемRadioButton.isSelected()) {
        typeOfUse = "Запорный с сильфонным уплотнением";
    } else if (невозратнаяОбратнаяRadioButton.isSelected()) {
        typeOfUse = "Обратный";
    } else if (невозвратноЗапорнаяRadioButton1.isSelected()) {
        typeOfUse = "Невозвратно-запорный";
    } else if (невозвратноПриемнаяRadioButton.isSelected()) {
        typeOfUse = "Бабочка";
    } else if (задвижкиRadioButton.isSelected()) {
        typeOfUse = "Задвижка";
    } else if (ножевыеЗадвижкиRadioButton.isSelected()) {
        typeOfUse = "Ножевая задвижка";
    }

    if (фланцеваяRadioButton.isSelected()) {
        connectionType = "Фланцевое";
    } else if (межфланцеваяRadioButton.isSelected()) {
        connectionType = "Межфланцевое";
    } else if (муфтоваяRadioButton.isSelected()) {
        connectionType = "Муфтовое";
    } else if (штуцернаяRadioButton.isSelected()) {
        connectionType = "Штуцерная";
    } else if (цапковаяRadioButton.isSelected()) {
        connectionType = "Цапковое";
    } else if (подПриваркуRadioButton.isSelected()) {
        connectionType = "Под приварку";
    }

    if (проходнаяRadioButton.isSelected()) {
        typeOfConstruction = "Проходной";
    } else if (угроловаяRadioButton.isSelected()) {
        typeOfConstruction = "Угловой";
    }


}
```

Думаю что  проблема легко решается, но увы не получается найти решение, пробовал и clear() и пустое значение забивать в JTextArea, да что только не делал. Чувствую, что где то рядом, но не как не добраться.

А вот класс реализации поиска по List. Вот его я и нашел на просторах интернета и до конца сам не осознал. Оптимизировал под свой код. Всё работает, но до конца не могу понять как.

```
public class ArmatureSearch extends ArmatureList {
private String name;
private String typeOfUse;// тип использования
private String connectionType;// тип соединения
private String bodyComposition;// матриал корпуса
private String typeOfConstruction;// Конструкция (проход/угл)
private Integer DN;  // DN
private Integer minPn;
private Integer maxPn;
private Integer fig;// fig.

public ArmatureSearch setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    return this;
}

public ArmatureSearch setTypeOfUse(String typeOfUse) {
    this.typeOfUse = typeOfUse;
    return this;
}

public ArmatureSearch setConnectionType(String connectionType) {
    this.connectionType = connectionType;
    return this;
}
public ArmatureSearch setBodyComposition(String bodyComposition) {
    this.bodyComposition = bodyComposition;
    return this;
}
public ArmatureSearch setTypeOfConstruction(String typeOfConstruction) {
    this.typeOfConstruction = typeOfConstruction;
    return this;
}

public ArmatureSearch setDN(Integer DN) {
    this.DN = DN;
    return this;
}


public ArmatureSearch setMinPn(Integer minPn) {
    this.minPn = minPn;
    return this;
}

public ArmatureSearch setMaxPn(Integer maxPn) {
    this.maxPn = maxPn;
    return this;
}

public ArmatureSearch setFig(Integer fig) {
    this.fig = fig;
    return this;
}

public List<CreateArmature> search(Collection<CreateArmature> valvesList) {
    return valvesList.stream()
            .filter(createArmature->name == null || createArmature.getName().equals(name))
            .filter(createArmature->typeOfUse == null || createArmature.getTypeOfUse().equals(typeOfUse))
            .filter(createArmature->connectionType == null || createArmature.getConnectionType().equals(connectionType))
            .filter(createArmature->bodyComposition == null || createArmature.getBodyComposition().equals(bodyComposition))
            .filter(createArmature->typeOfConstruction == null || createArmature.getTypeOfConstruction().equals(typeOfConstruction))
            .filter(createArmature->typeOfConstruction == null || createArmature.getTypeOfConstruction().equals(typeOfConstruction))
            .filter(createArmature->DN == null || createArmature.getDN()==(DN))
            .filter(createArmature->rangeOf(createArmature.getPN(), minPn, maxPn))
            .filter(createArmature->fig == null || createArmature.getFig()==(fig))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private boolean rangeOf(Integer value, Integer min, Integer max) {
    if (min==null && max==null) return true;
    if (min!=null && max==null && min<=value) return true;
    if (max!=null && min==null && max>=value) return true;
    if (max!=null && min!=null && max>=value && min<=value) return true;
    return false;
}}
```

Повторяю:
Как сделать так, чтобы в JTextArea после нажатия JButton "Начать поиск арматуры" не добавлялся результат поиска к прошлому результату, а был как после 1го нажатия JButton, а не увеличивался итд.

PS
Не ругайтесь, знаком с программированием около 2х недель.
Посмотрел несколько коротких уроков по Java, и мне захотелось написать программу которая поможет лично мне на моей работе. Дошел до изучения Swing (через GUI), а как мне реализовать поиск по List нашел на просторах интернета, парился , не мог понять как вообще по характеристика что то искать. создавал объекты другого класса и пытался как то по ним искать и не понял как. Но нашел решение в реализации поиска через List. В будущем дойду до SQL итд итп, а пока хотелось бы так вот доделать эту прогу. (делаю просто так как хобби, для общего развития).

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Как сделать так, чтобы в JTextArea после нажатия JButton "Начать поиск арматуры" не добавлялся результат поиска к прошлому результату, а был как после 1го нажатия JButton, а не увеличивался итд.

Comment: Вам следует упростить и отладить часть кода, которая меняет содержимое `JTextArea` при нажатии на кнопку, возможно стоит добавить ещё одну кнопку и оттестировать очистку `JTextArea`.  В данном виде вопрос содержит множество несущественныз подробностей.

Comment: У вас setValvesListList статический, попробуйте ПЕРЕД тем как добавлять элементы вызывать clear();  Всё очень громоздко, выложите код на сторонний ресурс, и опишите как должно работать. Полностью описывать весь код не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось всё  просто.

Нужно было  clear() лист по которому создавался лист для вывода в JTextArea, но после добавления результата в JTextArea.

вот код условия из кнопки с добавленным  ArmatureList.valvesList.clear();

```
            List<CreateArmature> searchResult = new ArmatureSearch()
                    .setBodyComposition(bodyComposition)
                    .setTypeOfUse(typeOfUse)
                    .setConnectionType(connectionType)
                    .setTypeOfConstruction(typeOfConstruction)
                    .setDN(dn)
                    .setMinPn(pn)
                    .search(ArmatureList.valvesList);
            textAreaResultsSearchArm.setText(String.valueOf(searchResult));

            ArmatureList.valvesList.clear();
```

ps
в след. раз буду более понятно и ёмко писать. Всем спасибо!